# SAP connection in VBA - Error 424 Object Required

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I was able to edit this code and make VBA connect with SAP.

When I make the call the code stops working on the first line of second code - `Session.findById...` and gives the error

> Run time error 424: Object Required

Follow the codes and the error occurs on the commented line in the second code.

Full code of the SAP connection module:

```
Global Session

Sub SAP_Login(ByVal Transacao As String)

Dim SapGui
Dim Applic
Dim Connection
Dim Session
Dim WshShell
Dim mensagem As String

On Error GoTo DESLOGADO
Set Session = GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine.Children(0).Children(0)
    
GoTo LOGADO

DESLOGADO:

'Abre o Sap instalado na sua máquina
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", vbNormalFocus

'inicia a variável com o objeto SAP
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until WshShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop

Set WshShell = Nothing

Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Set Applic = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine

Set Connection = Applic.OpenConnection("NEA Dow Prod - ERP Central Component (ECC) (SSO) (001)", True)

Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

'DADOS PARA FAZER O LOGIN NO SISTEMA
'On Error Resume Next
'Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "800" 'client do sistema

Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

LOGADO:

With Session
    .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/o"
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n"
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = Transacao
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
    'possivel texto de erro sap vai aparecer no excel
    mensagem = .findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
      
    If mensagem <> Empty Then
        Application.StatusBar = mensagem
    End If
End With

'ESSA PARTE SAI DO SISTEMA POS A EXECUÇÃO DO CÓDIGO

'Set session = Nothing
'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
'connection.CloseSession ("ses[0]")
'Set connection = Nothing
'Set sap = Nothing

End Sub
```

Second code that makes the call and continues the SAP script (it's on a button):

```
Private Sub EXTRAIR_Click()

Call SAP_Login("coois")
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[2]/menu[0]/menu[0]").Select 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR BEGINS!!!
    Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = "nd87309"
    Session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 8
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtS_ECKST-LOW").Text = "07062022"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtS_ECKST-HIGH").Text = "07062022"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").SetCurrentCell -1, ""
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").SelectAll
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").ContextMenu
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").SelectContextMenuItemByPosition "0"
    
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial
    MsgBox "Copiado com Sucesso"

End Sub
```

Comment: You'd better debug your code, you'd see that Session Is Nothing, hence the error (and you wouldn't tag it as a SAP GUI Scripting issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

`Dim Session`

inside `SAP_Login`: that variable will "hide" the Global variable with the same name, so when that sub exits the Global is still `Nothing`.  Remove the local variable declaration so only the Global one remains.